# mark part of a plain text

Tags: javascript, unicode, unicode-string, unicode-escapes

I want to somehow mark a part of a plain text to emphasize that without putting extra characters around that.
I figured out that I can use the [combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks) and used `\u0332`, but when I tried to emphasize a string including numbers and white spaces, I realized that the character doesn't combine with them (will be combined with the next character):

```js
console.log("8 o'clock".replace(/./g, a => a + "\u{0332}"));
```

I'm trying to find any appropriate combining character or make `\u0332` to combine with all other characters, or any idea like this to mark a plain text.

Comment: Seems to work fine; U+0332 doesn’t look good on _all_ characters. Note that it looks like `8_ _o_'_c_l_o_c_k_` due to the _monospace_ font; you’d need a proportional font for the combining property to take effect. You could do that with `console.log("%c" + "8 o'clock".replace(/./g, a => a + "\u{0332}"), "font-family: sans-serif;");`, but then you might just as well do `console.log("%c8 o’clock", "text-decoration: underline;");`. And why stop there? Mark a part like this: `console.log("%c8%c o’clock", "font-weight: bold; background: yellow; color: green; padding: 0.5em; border-radius: 50%");`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thank you very much for your response. I wasn't aware of this browser console functionality but I need to use the string somewhere else as a plain text output. I used `console.log` just to show the result using the code snippet.